# Python 2.7 CSV: How to remove duplicate rows based on a value

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file with the following format:

```
name, id, date, score
chris, 55, 5/22/2014, 70
pete, 56, 5/22/2014, 100
chris, 55, 5/22/2014, 100
```

I'm trying to sort by name, then locate the duplicate entries and remove the duplicate with the lowest score.  I've got the sorting done, I'm stuck on the rest.

SORTING CODE:

```
import csv

sortedlist = None

with open('my_file.csv', 'r') as zfile:
    sortedlist = sorted(zfile, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=False)
    for line in sortedlist:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print line
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you want (*using functionali style*):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import csv
from pprint import pprint
from operator import itemgetter


INPUT = """\
name, id, date, score
chris, 55, 5/22/2014, 70
pete, 56, 5/22/2014, 100
chris, 55, 5/22/2014, 100"""


reader = csv.reader(INPUT.split("\n"))
rows = iter(reader)
next(rows)  # skip header
sort_key = itemgetter(0, 3)
sorted_rows = reversed(sorted(rows, key=sort_key))
unique_rows = dict((row[1], row) for row in sorted_rows)

pprint(unique_rows)
```

**Output:**

```
$ python -i foo.py
{' 55': ['chris', ' 55', ' 5/22/2014', ' 100'],
 ' 56': ['pete', ' 56', ' 5/22/2014', ' 100']}
>>>
```

Sorting this output by name is easy:

```
>>> pprint(sorted(unique_rows.values(), key=itemgetter(0)))
[['chris', ' 55', ' 5/22/2014', ' 100'], ['pete', ' 56', ' 5/22/2014', ' 100']]
```

*Notes:*

- Use [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to read the data because it's clearly comma value separated (CSV).
- Sort the rows based on a key of `0th` (*name*) item *and* `3rd` (*score*) item.
- Reverse the sorting order from lowest score to highest score (*you'll see why*)
- Map this to a dict (*key/value pairs*) lowest to highest scores.

Any duplicate entries based on id with a higher score will supercede those of a lower score
so you get the output/result that you're looking for.